# Solar LiFePo4 Battery sudden discharge at end of the night

Tags: troubleshooting, lifepo4

[image]
Image above showed performance of the system over the past week. Blue is battery in W (this takes into account 2 230w/h batteries. Orange is the current from the PV. Grey is the W used by the LED during the night.
The drop I am referring to is on the night of 29th before the 30th.
The weird pattern on the 26th night is due to an internal problem with my task manager, just ignore that section

I am not an electrical engineer but have some understanding of electrical components. Sorry for noobness, hopefully you guys can change that

tl;dr :LiFePo4 batteries discharged really fast for no apparent reason. why would LiFePo do this?

I have 2 230Wh 13 V LiFePo4 batteries in my outdoor lights. Panel is 18V 70w and LED is 30w. I don't have other data.
They on my property and off the grid.
New system, less than 10 cycles.

They have a 30 W LED attached and a 70w Solar Panel to charge the batteries.

Batteries charge during the day and discharge at night.
I live in a warm environment North Hemisphere, 34 F is very rare even in winter. It has not gotten colder than freezing yet this month

Usually one battery stays at 100% while the other discharges from 100% to about 30% to then recharges during the morning. They rotate every 3 or 4 days.

Yesterday battery A (battery on call) dropped from 32% to 5% and battery B (not on call) went from 100% to 58%

I get this data from an app and not physically since they are 15 feet from grade. I pull data every 15 minutes into an Excel sheet and plot stuff out to keep track.

I checked the battery status for maybe 1 hour and they started charging: battery A to 7% then 9% and 12% and battery B to 59% then 70%. So it seems to be charging normally.
Why would it discharge so quickly?

Thanks in advance

Edit: 230Wh not Ah

Comment: Was it unusually cold?

Comment: Low voltage cutout is crucial for longevity as well as balanced batteries, better to use a trickle charger

Comment: How are you measuring state of charge?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Not colder than the nights before. I live in a pretty warm environment, below 40 F is the coldest it has been all december

Comment: @RoyC The app pulls the % of each battery and I do a simple excel function to calculate W/h left in it. The app can pull other data too though like Battery Volt, panel Volt, LED power.

Comment: "The app pulls the % of each battery" Where does this information come from? What kind of charger is between the solar panels and the battery?

Comment: How many cycles do you estimate the cells have seen in their lifetime? Partial counts.

Comment: @ocrdu The chinese manufacturer programmed an app but it's not very good so I just pull data via the API. The charger is MPPT. Battery voltage 13 V

Comment: @rdtsc very new system. I installed this on Dec 23 so not even a week old. 7 cycles maybe? mostly at 70% DoD except for the incident where it reached 95% DoD

Comment: Which controller? Show us your data. -"Not colder than the nights before"_ - and that temperature was?

Comment: One place you say "18 V LiFePo4 batteries" and another "Battery voltage 13 V".  Without some clear details nobody's going to be able to help.

Comment: @BruceAbbott The temperature since the install ranged from 38 F to 80F. It is unusual for it to get colder. Controller is MTTP, I don't have much more info on that

Comment: @Finbarr just edited the post. Batteries are 13 V each and the solar panels are 18 V. I will change the post to include better data

Comment: Have the 13V packs ever been exposed to 18V charge?  How is the charge regulated?

Comment: What are the graph scales?  _"Usually one battery stays at 100% while the other discharges from 100% to about 30% to then recharges during the morning. **They rotate every 3 or 4 days**"_- How does this work?  _"Controller is MTTP, I don't have much more info on that"_ - since controller operation is crucial to understanding the problem, can't you give us a bit more than that? Surely the controller has a model number etc.? Where did you get it?

Comment: My gut feel is that the 70W panels aren't sufficient to charge the batteries enough to supply 30W LEDs during the absence of daylight but it's hard to figure out what's going on from what you've posted.